# Join coordinates in 3d plot using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, plot, 3d

I am trying to join two coordinates (nodes) within a 3d plot using `pgfplots`. The problem that I am facing is that the joining line is not even touching the endpoints. I am guessing that the line is being projected into some plane but how can I overcome this issue?

Here is the MWE, where the magenta-colored line illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    
%   s(t) curve
    \addplot3 [
        mesh,
        color=blue,
        domain=-0.7:0.7
    ] (x, x, -{2/5}*x^2);
    
%   dots on s(t)
    \addplot3 [
        color=blue,
        draw=none, 
        mark=*, 
        mark size=1.5
        ] table [row sep=crcr] {%
         0    0    0    \\
        } node (S) [at start,above] {$s(t)$};
    
%   r(t)
    \addplot3 [
        mesh,
        color=blue,
        domain=-0.7:0.707
    ] (x, {0.5*(5*0.3-(-4*x^2+20*0.2-20*x*0.3+25*0.3^2)^0.5)}, {-0.2+0.5*0.3*(2*x-5*0.3+(-4*x^2+20*0.2-20*x*0.3+25*0.3^2)^0.5)});
    
%   dots on r(t)
    \addplot3 [
        color=blue,
        draw=none, 
        mark=*, 
        mark size=1.5
        ] table [row sep=crcr] {%
        0   -0.5        -0.05\\
        } node (R) [at start,below] {$r(t)$};
        
    \draw[thick,magenta] (R) -- (S);
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you connecting the nodes? You should connecting through the coordinates. Because as you specified, the nodes are actually above and below the coordinates (`node (S) [at start,above] {$s(t)$}` and `node (R) [at start,below] {$r(t)$}`):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    
%   s(t) curve
    \addplot3 [
        mesh,
        color=blue,
        domain=-0.7:0.7
    ] (x, x, -{2/5}*x^2);
    
%   dots on s(t)
    \addplot3 [
        color=blue,
        draw=none, 
        mark=*, 
        mark size=1.5
        ] table [row sep=crcr] {%
         0    0    0    \\
        } node (S) [at start,above] {$s(t)$};
    
%   r(t)
    \addplot3 [
        mesh,
        color=blue,
        domain=-0.7:0.707
    ] (x, {0.5*(5*0.3-(-4*x^2+20*0.2-20*x*0.3+25*0.3^2)^0.5)}, {-0.2+0.5*0.3*(2*x-5*0.3+(-4*x^2+20*0.2-20*x*0.3+25*0.3^2)^0.5)});
    
%   dots on r(t)
    \addplot3 [
        color=blue,
        draw=none, 
        mark=*, 
        mark size=1.5
        ] table [row sep=crcr] {%
        0   -0.5        -0.05\\
        } node (R) [at start,below] {$r(t)$};
        
    \draw[thick,magenta] (0,0,0) -- (0,-0.5,-0.05);
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, I did not think of joining the coordinates... I was very focused in creating nodes to join them. Thanks